# Structure movie lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I'm trying to set up a proper database-design, but I'm stuck.
Here is what I'm trying to save.

Every user can define a vote history list from imdb looking like [this](http://www.imdb.com/mymovies/list?l=19736607).

Two users can define the same list.

First I want to be able to save each list as an `imdb_vote_history_list` - list.

```
class ImdbVoteHistoryList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vote_history_list
  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies
  # Fields
  # id (Integer) - defined by the user
end
```

Each list should be unique and is being defined by it's ID (given in the link).
Each list has and belongs to many movies, as in the code above.

Each user should be able to pick a name for every list.
So instead of saying

> Each imdb_vote_history_list belongs_to user

I create a new relation called `vote_history_list`.

```
class VoteHistoryList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :imdb_vote_history_lists
  belongs_to :user

  # Fields
  # name (String)
end
```

Here the user can pick any name for the list, without interference with other user's names.

Is this a good way to store the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the theoretical database design view this is the right approach.
For example the entity relationship model describes it this way. You can have relationships between entities and attributes at those relationships. If you map those to a relational model (database tables) you get a table for the relationship containing references to both entites and all additional information.
This is what theory can tell us about it :)